# jCarousel not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I've been trying to get this working for the last hour, but I can't for the life of me, so I thought i'd ask here.

I have this code:

```
<ul id="myCarousel">
<% foreach (var date in entryDates)
   { %>
 <li>
  <div style="text-align:center;width:60px;">
     <span class="headerSpan" id="day_<%=date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>">abc</span>
  </div>
  <input class="timeInput narrow" type="text" id="time_<%= date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>"/>
  <input class="subsInput narrow" type="text" id="subs_<%=date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") %>"/>
 </li>
<% } %>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').jcarousel({
            scroll: 7,
            animation: 1000,
            buttonNextHTML: "<span id='next'>Next</span>",
            buttonPrevHTML: "<span id='previous'>Previous</span>"
        });
    });    
</script>
```

It works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but it simply will not scroll in IE.

Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your code.

However on [jCarousel's documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) it's written it has been tested on IE6 and 7 but not IE8:

> jCarousel has been tested and works on
>   the following browsers:
>
> ```
> * Internet Explorer 6 (PC)
> * Internet Explorer 7 (PC)
> * FireFox 1.5.0.6 (PC/Mac/Linux)
> * Opera 9.01 (PC/Mac)
> * Safari 2.0.4 (Mac)
> * Safari 3.1.0 (PC)
> * Konqueror 3.4.0 (Linux)
> ```

Is it working in IE6?

For using it, I know that [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) is working in every browser.

Comment: I've not got IE6 or 7 installed on this machine. I have tried it in IE8 compatibility mode and it's the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

It does not scroll coz of this line #373 (defenition of function "get"):

```
return $('>.jcarousel-item-' + i, this.list);
```

This selector returns 0 elements, but it must be 1. If you replace that on

```
return $('.jcarousel-item-' + i, this.list);
```

you get working scroll.

">" does not work in IE6 and works with a bug in IE7. Moreover, it does not work in IE8 in my project (DOCTYPE is XHTML 1.0 Strict, document.compatMode is CSS1Compat). [This](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/) says that ">" should work in IE8, but actually it does not. Hmm, looks strange.

**UPD**
[Post](http://www.celticwolf.com/blog/2010/03/15/ie8-child-selector-weirdness/) about wierdness of ">" in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

I have used jCarousel in much projects. I think it's ok with IE 7, 8 and 9.
To test that. You can go to http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ and try to run their examples in browsers that your code's getting problem. So you will know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run copy on the server. On local copy IE "kill" JS-scripts